# How can PyQt be used to select a save location for a new Folder

Tags: python, pyqt, qfiledialog

I am trying to use PyQt to open a file dialog and then allow the user to select a new location to create a new directory which will be used in the program.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
dialog = QFileDialog()
dialog.setOption(QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly, True)
dialog.setWindowTitle(title)
dialog.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog.AcceptOpen)
dialog.setNameFilter(nameFilter)
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.Directory)
if dialog.exec_() == QFileDialog.Accepted:
    return dialog.selectedFiles()[0]
```

However in the file dialog all the files are still shown and their is no option to select a directory if the user want to overwrite it.

The wanted outcome would show just the directories in the explorer.

Is there a way of doing this using PyQt file dialogs?

Comment: I did not understand you, could you explain me better

Comment: I want the user to be able to select a location to create a new directory where any files they generate will be stored. I would also like the user to be able to select an existing directory as this new directory location which will then be overwritten. When they are selecting the location from the dialog it would also be good if it only showed directories and not files. Thanks!

Comment: Replacing `dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.Directory)` with `dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.DirectoryOnly)` works for me.

Comment: I have tried this and both directories and files are still shown. When I remove the setAcceptMode then it only shows the directories but then I cannot choose a save location.